# PowerShell: find all matches in a string from array and count

Tags: powershell

I am trying to match all string values of $array2 with $array expecting result to be "five" but it is giving "two" result. However, if use numbers such as "1","2" in an array then it is working as expected.

Please help me to correct below powershell code.

```
Code : 


$matchingCount = 0
$array = @('blue','red','purple','pink')
$array2 = @('blue','red','blue','yellow','blue','blue','a','d')

$array | ForEach-Object {
    if ($array2 -match $_) {
        $matchingCount++
    }
}


 #Write-Host "Number of matching values: $matchingCount"
 If ($matchingCount -eq "0")
{

 $number="None"
 }
 ElseIf  ($matchingCount -eq "1")
 {
$number="One"
 }
 ElseIf ($matchingCount -eq "2")
 {
  $number="Two"
 }
 ElseIf ($matchingCount -eq "3")
 {
 $number="Three"
 }
 ElseIf ($matchingCount -eq "4")
 {
  $number="Four"
 }
 ElseIf ($matchingCount -eq "5")
 {
  $number="Five"
 }
  Else
 {
 $number="Multiple"
 }

 $number
```

Comment: how could it possibly give you "five" when `$array` only has 4 elements in it? are you sure you didnt want `$array2 | ForEach-Object ...` instead ?

Comment: Because there are four blues and one red so i am expecting result equal five values as match. Perhaps my logic is not right but i want to match all words in a string with other values in a variable. Please help to correct the logic if it is not right.

Comment: You need to compare the longer array with the shorter array, not the shorter array with the longer array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$matchingCount = 0
$array = @('blue','red','purple','pink')
$array2 = @('blue','red','blue','yellow','blue','blue','a','d')


$array2 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($array -eq $_) {
        $matchingCount++
    }
}

$matchingCount
```